# Adding composer text box value to an array?

Tags: iphone, core-data, sendmessage

1. I have the coredata showing in text fields the data stored

   ```
   in view didload: tfEmail.text = editEmp.email;
   ```
2. the message composer works as well, but if I want to use the email data to include in my message, I get the trouble...

   ```
   NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"employee@example.com"];
   [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
   ```
3. what I need to do is to include the tfEmail in the NSArray, so if I try

   ```
   NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"%@", tfEmail.text];
   ```

   I will get an error

   ```
   Too many arguments to function arrayWithObject
   ```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tryig to pass a string to the array initializer but are actually passing in *two* strings. This line should be changed:

```
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"%@", tfEmail.text];
```

You are passing in two string objects, `@"%@"` and `tfEmail.text`. Try removing the format string, like so:

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tfEmail.text];
```

If you wanted to keep the format, wrap those strings as follows:

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tfEmail.text]];
```